# Extracting Words using nltk from German Text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I am trying to extract words from a german document, when I use th following method as described in the nltk tutorial, I fail to get the words with language specific special characters.

```
ptcr = nltk.corpus.PlaintextCorpusReader(Corpus, '.*');
words = nltk.Text(ptcr.words(DocumentName))
```

What should I do to get the list of words in the document?

An example with `nltk.tokenize.WordPunctTokenizer()` for the german phrase `Veränderungen über einen Walzer` looks like:

```
In [231]: nltk.tokenize.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(u"Veränderungen über einen Walzer")

Out[231]: [u'Ver\xc3', u'\xa4', u'nderungen', u'\xc3\xbcber', u'einen', u'Walzer']
```

In this example "ä" is treated as a delimiter,even though "ü" is not.

Comment: what do you get instead of the word list ? Do you know the encoding of your input files ?

Comment: I get a word-list that is separated abnormally, for example the german letter 'ä' is treated as a separator. the encoding is 'utf-8'.

Comment: it is strange because the PlaintextCorpusReader uses WordPunctTokenizer() which handle unicode to tokenize text. Could you give me an exemple of bug using nltk.tokenize.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(u"you buggy text")

Answer (score 12):

Call PlaintextCorpusReader with the parameter encoding='utf-8':

```
ptcr = nltk.corpus.PlaintextCorpusReader(Corpus, '.*', encoding='utf-8')
```

Edit: I see... you have two separate problems here:

a) Tokenization problem: When you test with a literal string from German, 
you *think* you are
entering unicode. In fact you are telling python to take the bytes
between the quotes and convert them into a unicode string. But your bytes are being
misinterpreted. Fix: Add the following line at the very top of your
source file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

All of a sudden your constants will be seen and tokenized correctly:

```
german = u"Veränderungen über einen Walzer"
print nltk.tokenize.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(german)
```

Second problem: It turns out that `Text()` does not use unicode! If you
pass it a unicode string, it will try to convert it to a pure-ascii
string, which of course fails on non-ascii input. Ugh.

Solution: My recommendation would be to avoid using `nltk.Text` entirely, and work with the corpus readers directly. (This is in general a good idea: See `nltk.Text`'s own documentation).

But if you *must* use `nltk.Text` with German data, here's how: Read your 
data properly so it can be tokenized, but then "encode" your unicode back to a list of `str`. For German, it's
probably safest to just use the Latin-1 encoding, but utf-8 seems to work
too.

```
ptcr = nltk.corpus.PlaintextCorpusReader(Corpus, '.*', encoding='utf-8');

# Convert unicode to utf8-encoded str
coded = [ tok.encode('utf-8') for tok in ptcr.words(DocumentName) ]
words = nltk.Text(coded)
```

Comment: this gives me the list of words, when I encapsulate with nltk.Text I get "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)". I think this is an encoding decoding problem.

Comment: You definitely have an encoding problem, or rather two. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/
I'm not sure your text is getting the right encoding, since WordPunctTokenizer in the demo handles the words fine. And so does PunktWordTokenizer.

Comment: I checked that but I think they handle the problem implicitly :D.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a simple regular expression. The following suffices if you want just the words; it will swallow all punctuation:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\w+", "Veränderungen über einen Walzer.".decode("utf-8"), re.U)
[u'Ver\xe4nderungen', u'\xfcber', u'einen', u'Walzer']
```

Note that `re.U` changes the meaning of `\w` in the RE based on the current locale, so make sure that's set correctly. I have it set to `en_US.UTF-8` which is apparently good enough for your example.

Also note that `"Veränderungen über einen Walzer".decode("utf-8")` and `u"Veränderungen über einen Walzer"` are different strings.