# Split/decompose German words in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I need to split/decompose German composed words in Python. An example:

```
Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän
```

should be decomposed to:

```
[Donau, Dampf, Schiff, Fahrt, Gesellschaft, Kapitän]
```

First I found wordaxe, but it did not work. Than I came across NLTK, but still don't understand if that is smth. I need.

A solution with an example would be really great!

Comment: @unknown: If you give -1 for the question, you should explain 'why'.

Comment: Why did wordaxe not work?

Comment: I don't know. First of all I could not download the package via pypi, but it was listed there. Than I installed it by downloading it manually from sourceforge. There is nearly no documentation for wordaxe and code looks really horrible (with variables named in German, test functions embedded into the base classes, etc.) Finally, from reading the source I concluded that I need to do smth like:

h = wordaxe.DCWHyphenator.DCWHyphenator('DE', 5)
result = h.hyphenate(u'Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän')

And the result is my input. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149709/extracting-words-using-nltk-from-german-text