# Named Entity Recognition Systems for German Texts

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working on a **Named Entity Recognition (NER)** project in which I got a large amount of text in the sense that it is too much to read or skim read. Therefore, I want to **create an overview of what is mentioned** by extracting *named entities* (places, names, times, maybe topics) and create an index of kind (entity, list of pages/lines where it is mentioned). I have worked through [Standford's NLP lecture](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224n/cs224n.1214/), (parts of) Eisenstein's [*Introduction to NLP*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-natural-language-processing) book found some literature and systems for English texts. As **my corpus is in German**, I would like to ask how I can approach this problem. Also, this is my first NLP project, so I would not know if I could solve this challenge even if texts were in English.

As a first step

- are there German NER systems out there which I could use?

The further roadmap of my project is:

- How can I avoid mapping misspellings or rare names to a `NUL`/`UNK` token? This is relevant because there are also some historic passages that use words no longer in use or that follow old orthography. I think the relevant terms are **tokenisation** or **stemming**.
- I thought about fine-tuning or transfer learning the base NER model to a corpus of historic texts to improve NER.

A major challenge is that there is **no annotated dataset** for my corpus available and I could only manually annotate a tiny fraction of it. So I would be happy for hints on German annotated datasets which I could incorporate into my project.

Thank you in advance for your inputs and fruitful discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Most good NLP toolkits can perform NER in German:

- [Stanford NLP](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html#German)
- [Spacy](https://spacy.io/models/de)
- probably NLTK and [OpenNLP](https://nnovakova.github.io/opennlp-ner-annotaton/) as well

What is crucial to understand is that using NER software like the above means using a *pretrained* model, i.e. a model which has been previously trained on some standard corpus with standard annotated entities.

Btw you can usually find the original annotated dataset by looking at the documentation. There's [one NER corpus](https://www.inf.uni-hamburg.de/en/inst/ab/lt/resources/data/germaner.html) here.

This is convenient and might suit your goal, but sometimes it doesn't collect exactly every that you would like it to collect, especially if your corpus is from a very specific domain. If you need more specific NER, you must train your own model and this requires obtaining some annotated data (i.e. manually annotating or paying somebody to do it).

Even in this case, a NER model is statistical and it will unavoidably make some mistakes, don't expect perfect results.

About misspellings or rare names: a NER model doesn't care (or not too much) about the actual entity, because it's not primarily based on the words in the entity. It's based on indications in the surrounding text, for example in the sentence "It was announced by Mr XYZ that the event would take place in July", the NER model should find 'Mr XYZ' as a person due to "announced by" and 'July' as a date because of "take place in". However if the language used in the corpus is very different from the training data used for the model, the performance could be very bad.

Comment: Just used Spacy's model ```de_core_news_md```. The results are o.k. but not amazing. Will need to check Stanford's and NLTK's PoS / NER  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149709/extracting-words-using-nltk-from-german-text) a slightly older implementation with NLTK